# Straight hand in poker

Tags: poker-strategy, strategy

Is it a straight if let's say you have a 3 and a 4 and down on the table are a K an A and a 2?

Answer (score 1):

No. Straights are from `23456` to `TJQKA` (where `T` is 10 in a useful representation of just 1 character). A special lowest case exists as `A2345`.

Assuming `KA234` as a valid straight comes from a wrong assumption from a [popular dice game](https://cardgames.io/yahtzee/), although such assumption is also wrong in that game, but also widely spread.